# jquery datalist only showing 1st option in Firefox

Tags: ajax, firefox, datalist

I have a datalist generated using ajax call, say the DOM looks like following

```
<input list='list' type='text'>
<datalist id="list">
  <option>aa</option>
  <option>ab</option>
  <option>ac</option>
</datalist>
```

Type "a" as input should give me a dropdown of all 3 options, which works  well in Chrome, however in Firefox, it only shows me the first option even if I can see all 3 listed in the DOM.

This only happens when I generate the dropdown options, using a pre-defined dropdown list doesn't have this issue.

Comment: For whoever comes later in for this problem, <datalist> is deprecated when building search list since it doesn't have stable performance cross different browsers and html versions. A more common solution is to use <ul> instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your browser and html version

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp